# Live streaming video player

Tags: accessibility, video-player, wcag

I have a live streaming video player that can be hidden by collapsing its parent container. I'm wondering if such a player must have Stop/Pause buttons in terms of accessibility. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to clarify, if someone collapses the player parent container does the video stop playing automatically? Does it resume if you expand the parent container again? A simple fiddle would make this easier to answer as there are several things to consider. But the short answer is yes, you need play and pause buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Maria, just because it's hidden to a sighted user, doesn't mean it will be hidden to a user who is blind. WCAG 2.2.2 addresses this specifically: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#pause-stop-hide.